# PHP FFMpeg error ffprobe failed to execute command "D:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe" a.mov -show_streams -print_format json

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Fatal error: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command "D:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe" a.mov -show_streams -print_format json: Error Output: ffprobe version n4.3.1-30-g666d2fc6e2 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320 configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --disable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --disable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --e in D:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\php_ffmpeg\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe.php on line 264

```html
  line 264:
  try {
            $output = $this->ffprobe->command($commands);
            
        } catch (ExecutionFailureException $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to probe %s', $pathfile), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
```

Excute FFMpeg on CMD is all working fine with converting mov to mp4.
HERE is my php code:

```html
require 'plugin/php_ffmpeg/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'D:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
        'ffprobe.binaries' => 'D:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe',
        'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
        'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
    ));
    
    $video = $ffmpeg->open('a.mov');
    $video
        ->filters()
        ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
        ->synchronize();
    $video
        ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
        ->save('frame.jpg');
    $video
        ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'a.mp4');
```

PHP error is showing some part of config feedback but not all, stuck at enable-libx264 --enable-libx265. As I runed the command straight in CMD win10 which is all working:  a.mov -show_streams -print_format json :

```html
ffprobe version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-10-27T14:14:15.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.artwork: {
                    :   "source_type" : "douyin_beauty_me",
                    :   "data" : {
                    :     "exportType" : "export",
                    :     "editType" : "camera",
                    :     "musicId" : "6650279460488612609",
                    :     "videoId" : "5A5B5C2C-4518-4FD2-8DE5-DFF5CB568AE6",
                    :     "product" : "lv",
                    :     "infoStickerId" : "",
                    :     "videoEffectId" : "",
                    :     "os" : "ios",
                    :     "resourceTypeApplied" : "",
                    :     "launchMode" : "launch",
                    :     "stickerId" : "",
                    :     "appVersion" : "6.6.0",
                    :     "templateId" : ""
                    :   }
                    : }
    com.apple.quicktime.software: {"TEEditor":"0"},{"EHDRNet":"1"},{"isFastImport":"1"},{"transType":"2"},{"source":"5"}
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright: c053c1f017f900e53966660c5dfd5a56
  Duration: 00:00:22.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 846 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-27T14:14:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x480, 710 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-27T14:14:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
```

which means my FFMPeg is working fine, and i gave permission to IUSR,and the a.mov,even the temp forlder write and read excute premission under windows/system32/temp (by using cash).

Hope someone can provide some help here, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.